# Почему не срабатывает второй класс у span

Tags: css

Есть такой код, почему не срабатывает класс opted?

```
  <div class="reviews_dot">
                <span class="dot_bottom opted"></span>
                <span class="dot_bottom"></span>
                <span class="dot_bottom"></span>
                <span class="dot_bottom"></span>
                <span class="dot_bottom"></span>
                <span class="dot_bottom"></span>
                <span class="dot_bottom"></span>
            </div>

     .reviews_dot {
     text-align: center;
 }



 span.dot_bottom {
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     border: 1px #ffd200 solid;
     background-color: #fff;
     border-radius: 50%;
     display: inline-block;
 }

  span.dot_bottom:hover {
    border: 1px #323232 solid;
 }

 .opted {
     border: 1px #323232 solid;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указание стиля `span.dot_bottom` - более подробное/специфическое, чем просто `.opted`.

```css
.reviews_dot {
  text-align: center;
}

span.dot_bottom {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border: 1px #ffd200 solid;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

span.dot_bottom:hover {
  border: 1px #323232 solid;
}

span.opted {
  border: 1px #323232 solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="reviews_dot">
  <span class="dot_bottom opted"></span>
  <span class="dot_bottom"></span>
  <span class="dot_bottom"></span>
  <span class="dot_bottom"></span>
  <span class="dot_bottom"></span>
  <span class="dot_bottom"></span>
  <span class="dot_bottom"></span>
</div>
```

или

```css
.reviews_dot {
  text-align: center;
}

.dot_bottom {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border: 1px #ffd200 solid;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

span.dot_bottom:hover {
  border: 1px #323232 solid;
}

.opted {
  border: 1px #323232 solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="reviews_dot">
  <span class="dot_bottom opted"></span>
  <span class="dot_bottom"></span>
  <span class="dot_bottom"></span>
  <span class="dot_bottom"></span>
  <span class="dot_bottom"></span>
  <span class="dot_bottom"></span>
  <span class="dot_bottom"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек, забыл совсем про это...

Comment: @МаксимВоробьев На здоровье. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.